# Display prompt only once for update inside a loop

Tags: java

I would like to display the prompt only once. "Do you want to update" inside a loop which calls the update function.

```java
for (String person : persons) {
    if (id != null && !id.equals(person.getLocalId())) {
        System.out.print("ID is not same");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Do You Want to Update (Y/N) ? >");
        try {
            var ans = reader.readLine();
            if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && ans.length() > 0) {
                service.update(person.id);
            } else if (ans == null || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
sqlSession.commit();
```

Comment: Note: `ans == null` is statically provable to never be true. If it were, your code would have already thrown a `NullPointerException` two lines above when calling `equalsIgnoreCase` on the `ans` instance

Answer (score 0):

The body of a loop is executed as long as the loop condition is satisfied. For the special case of a "foreach" loop, it is executed once for each element in a collection.

So if you want to execute something only once, you have to move it out of the loop. I assume you only want to call the `service.update` method in a loop, not everything (i.e. you do not want to call `System.exit(0)` from inside your loop).

```java
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Do You Want to Update (Y/N) ? >");
    try {
        var ans = reader.readLine();
        if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && ans.length() > 0) {
            for (String person : persons) {
                service.update(person.id);
            }
        } else if (ans == null || ans.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    sqlSession.commit();
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. I have updated the code .There are more conditions and print statement  inside the loop.If they fulfilled only user will decide to update.

Comment: What now. Do you want to display it only once or once for each user? I am confused …

Comment: Only once. Since there are other print messages inside the loop. i want the execute them first to dispay id is not same. Then the prompt will display "Do you want to update".

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to add a boolean var which keeps track whether or not the user has already been prompted

Comment: Yes I believe so